# Rendering not display

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, render-layers, viewlayers

Earlier I tried I don't know what and only the head appeared on the render, when I press  <kbd>F12</kbd> it crashes and when I press  <kbd>F11</kbd> it displays a background with nothing, I've been looking for 1 hour and I haven't found any advice to help me

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: Hi, F11 shows the last render buffer in your session. If your render crashed, whatever frame you were rendering at that time was lost. When closing Blender, it empties out the render view node, you won't see your last render after opening the file again. So I think it is normal you don't see anything here.

Comment: but there is no solution?

Comment: even F12 there is nothing displayed

Comment: have you changed the compositor nodes or messed with the video sequence editor ?

Comment: What Blender version are you using and how powerful is your computer? - If you look in the bottom status bar when you start rendering (Blender 3.4.1) you'll see a progress report which on my M/C stays on 0% for a considerable time before the final rendered image appears making it look as if Blender has crashed. The rendered result has also used a very large amount of memory for a simple scene like that.

Comment: I am using the latest version and I have 32G ram, rtx 3060 and Amd Ryzen 7

Comment: no I had not touched anything

Comment: well, I'll have to start at 0 again, ouch...